# laravel elixir - combine compiled coffeescript/browserify files with sourcemaps

Tags: gulp, source-maps, laravel-elixir

I am trying to compile some CoffeeScript code into one file and browserify into another, then combine them. Everything works fine and each file gets a source-map in the build directory, but I can't combine them while generating a combined source-map.

Any way of doing this with elixir or do I need a Gulp pipe chain?

```
elixir(function(mix){
mix.browserify(['vendor-modules.js'], 'resources/assets/js/build/vendor-modules.js')
    .coffee([
        '_classes/*.coffee',

        'main.coffee',

        'react/home/*.coffee',
        'react/home.coffee',
    ], 'resources/assets/js/build/app-main.js')
    .scripts([
        'build/vendor-modules.js',
        'build/app-main.js',
    ], 'public/assets/js/app.js');
});
```